# How to concatenate value in app.config file?

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I have given path in app.config file like

`<add key="Pathname" value="g:\Imagefolder\" />` to save image,

Below `.vb` code

`Address=System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Pathname")`
`AxZKFPEngX1.SaveBitmap(Address+ "imgName.bmp")`

this isn't working fine &
if I provide `imgName.bmp` in config like

`value="g:\Imagefolder\imgName.bmp"`

it works fine & generate Img properly

but want to set image name Dynamic/pro-grammatically.

Comment: define 'this isn't working fine'. Error type, line, inner message...?
Btw, for concatenating strings it is prefered & before + (which can make a conversión)

Comment: It's just a `String`. Where a `String` came from is irrelevant to how you use it. Concatenating `Strings` is always the same. That said, if you want to combine partial file or folder paths then you should use the `Path.Combine` method.

Comment: Without having tested, I think that you're actually going to be getting the value back as an `Object` reference.  It's still a `String` though, so you just need to cast, e.g. with `CStr`.